# Overloading a method based on a type parameter

Tags: generics, scala, types

I'd like to have a method that can be called with or without a type parameter, and return a different value for each. Here's some obviously simplified code:

```
object Foo {
  def apply() = "Hello"
  def apply[T]() = 1
}
```

Calling it with a type parameter is fine:

```
scala> Foo[String]()
res1: Int = 1
```

But calling it without a type parameter doesn't work:

```
scala> Foo()
<console>:9: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method apply in object Foo of type [T]()Int
and  method apply in object Foo of type ()java.lang.String
match argument types ()
       Foo()
```

It's not a runtime problem, so adding an implicit dummy parameter doesn't help. Nor does having a restricted parameter (`Foo[Unit]()`). Is there any way of doing this that isn't ambiguous to the compiler?

Answer (score 2):

You are effectively overloading on the return type.
While neither Scala nor Java let you normally let you do so in this case it happens.

`Foo() : String` will work in this case but it remains questionable though if overloading on the return type is desirable.

Comment: You're right, `Foo():String` works. That's not really desirable though - the whole idea is to simply the calling code. What I really want to say is "I'm calling the version of this argument that takes zero type parameters, not the version that takes one type parameter".